# Why is Xcode randomly tries to close while I'm debugging?

Tags: xcode, debugging

while debugging my OS X app in XCode, when Xcode hasn't been the focus app for a short period of time, the warning asking if I'm sure I "want to close the project" pops up.  As if I manually tried to close the project.  And that "closing this workspace will stop the task..."  And of course, until I see this and cancel it, my debug is stopped.

I haven't shown any code because I'm not sure that's relevant.  If anyone has heard of this and knows why it's happening, I'd very much appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah. Do these two things.

1) going to system preferences, power settings (or something like that). Click restore defaults.

2) Go back one screen in System Preferences, and select Spotlight.  Click on the Privacy tab.  Click the “+” at the bottom, and select your Mac’s hard drive, and click Choose.  It’s now in the list. Close System Preferences, and reboot your Mac once.  Then, go back into System Preferences -> Spotlight -> Privacy and click on the drive in the list, then click “-” at the bottom of the list.

That should do it. This doesn't mean it won't happen again by the way. I had to do this about six months ago as well.